# In need of some guidance into QA

Tags: learning

## Hi everyone!

I hope you can lead me in the right direction. I'm want to transition into QA but , I'm not sure where to start. I'm really sorry if this is the wrong place to ask, I did try another place but wasn't getting any responses, so I hope this is ok.

I'm pretty much self taught with Ruby & Python, I've heard that it would be helpful in my search for a QA job and beyond.

What are some good materials to read? Or is good place to learn more online? Also has anyone heard about [Qatutor?](http://www.qatutor.com/)

I have a basic web stack whilst learning so Ruby, Rails, Javascript, Rspec, SQL, I've played around with minitest also, and some of the basic of TDD. With Python I was using it more for data analytics so matplotlib, numpy, and pandas. Would any of this be helpful in learning more about QA?

I was thinking I should learn about manual testing first then auto is that a good route or not? Also should I focus more on Python instead of Ruby; or something else I would like to stay with those two, but I've heard java might be useful...though we haven't gotten along since highschool.

Any other help or info is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's good to have some vocabulary:

- The [ISTQB Guide](http://istqbexamcertification.com/istqb-certification-the-definitive-guide/) can help you with that. I recommend reading the Chapter 1.
- If you are not familiar with the agile approach, a fast reading for the is also the [ISTQB Agile Guide](http://istqbexamcertification.com/what-is-the-istqb-agile-tester-extension-certification/). But for a deep dive, the [Agile Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321534468) book is excellent.

Now, about testing engineering, I recommend the following blog posts and videos:

Test Engineering:

- [What Exploratory Testing Is Not](http://www.developsense.com/blog/2011/12/what-exploratory-testing-is-not-part-1-touring/) | Part 1 of 5 (Worth read all five)
- [A Tester’s Commitments](http://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/652)
- [Exploratory Testing 3.0](http://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/1509)
- [General Functionality and Stability Test Procedure](http://www.satisfice.com/tools/procedure.pdf) (Paper from 2000, where James Bach (follow this guy on Twitter) shows his process for testing the Windows OS using exploratory testing)
- [Understanding exploratory testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-ItEKt_N_s)
- [Testing oracles - HICCUPPS](http://www.developsense.com/blog/2012/07/few-hiccupps/)
- [A Test is a Performance](http://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/1346)
- [Testing != test execution](https://testingjeff.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/testing-test-execution/)
- [Open Lecture by James Bach on Software Testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILkT_HV9DVU)
- [James Bach on testing in an agile software development team.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqwyMaHcjQE)

Regarding Automation, you will discover that Selenium is the most used tool at the moment. Given you have a strong background in programming and the fact that tutorials are technology dependent, I'll link more general resources.

- [How To Create a Test Automation Framework Architecture With Selenium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DO8KVe00kcU)
- [Page Object Pattern, Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html)
- BDD/Cucumber

  - http://martinfowler.com/bliki/GivenWhenThen.html
  - https://cucumber.io/docs/reference
  - https://lostechies.com/joeybeninghove/2010/06/01/cucumber/

Here you can find a small automation suite (using Cucumber and other small libraries to implement the Page Object Factory) that I wrote for a Edx-like education platform. It can give you a taste of all the pieces of an automation suite.
https://github.com/JoaoGFarias/OpenRedu/tree/cucumber_integration/features

Along with the preparation, practice makes the tester.
If you are not able to practice in your company, the [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/community/qa/) has a great QA community (both manual and auto).

Comment: Thank you so much for all the info you provided me! I this will definitely be helpful, Do you think it's also a good idea to learn about unit testing? Also, I'm pretty confident with python and ruby, should I start learning java, or is it more important to understand BDD, unit testing, and any programming language will suffice? Thanks again!

Comment: As a QA engineer, I think is good to have an idea of unit and integration testing - you should be able to, together with the devs, analyze when a feature is well covered by lower level tests (therefore, less needed of end-to-end tests).

Regarding the languages, for self-teaching, Ruby is a good way to go - most types of frameworks are originated or have a good mirror in Ruby. If one day you land in a Java project,  you can learn Java. The important thing is to learn good software development practices ('Clean Code', 'XP in Pratice' and 'Design Patterns' are good books for that).

Comment: Hi @JoãoGFarias just wanted to thank you again for the information that you gave me awhile ago, I wouldn't have know where to start or what was some good material to read without your input many thanks for taking the time to point me in the right direction. Also, thank you for confirming what I thought regarding the languages. I'll stick to what I know, if there's a need to learn Java then I will, and for the extra books. I'll be picking those up soon!

Answer (score 0):

firstly, i think it is better to choose an industry,such as IT,or Internet,or telecommunication.

then, choose one company which you want to go. check the hire information and QA job requirements. learn what it asks. basically, it needs the test theory knowledge and database knowledge,and some scripts knowledge. but the script is different depending on what the industry is.

finally, apply for the job.

Comment: Thank for your help, I do have some general knowledge on databases and some scripting knowledge as well. Testing theory is what I'm lacking, though. Is there a reason for going into a different field first? Meaning is those other field touching upon what QA testers do? Again thank you for you help!